# Dynamic side menu in Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

I need to create a dynamic side menu similar to below for my gui. Is there any widgets available in tkinter for doing the same? Any suggestions will be really helpful.

[image]

Comment: Do you know about the paned window of tkinter?

Comment: @Atlas435 No, I don't. That will be used to create dynamic side menu bar?

Comment: You could list tear down menus (`tkinter.Menu()`), but then you'd just have usual menus when you click on it. In order do make it a dynamic menu, you'd need a Frame in which labels are stacked on top of each other and their row number changes if a menu further up gets selected.
Or you create it as a Canvas and move the lower headers around if a menu gets selected.
Both might be crafted into an own class.